# Xubuntu 18.04: Letters became boxes after increasing swap size

Tags: xubuntu, swap

Turns out my root was on a separate disk with only a few gigs available. I accidentally made the swap fill nearly all of it by following this: https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/

Then it crashed. Now my Linux system is broken. Couldn't even log in at first, but then I set the swap back to default and now it automatically logs in. However, everything is still soundly broken:

- All letters are boxes.
- Can't open Settings.
- Can't open a normal terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> still works).
- Internet doesn't work because `libnettle.so.6` has invalid ELF header (whatever that means).
- Can't open folders.
- Can't open most programs.

I've made a huge mistake. Is it possible to revive my install or do I need to reinstall?

Comment: If it crashed and your turned the box off, did you `fsck` or *file system check* your partitions...  I would boot a *live* system and do that before using your system after any crash, as if it detects & fixes any flaws, you'll likely find a normal boot after it.

Comment: No joy on the fsck. Found and fixed many errors, but problem persists.

Comment: The shortest pain here will be a reinstall. If there is disk corruption, repair becomes technical and even if you know what you do, you never can be sure your repaired every bit

Comment: That's what I'll do then. Thanks.